# Eclipse CDT parsing C/C++ header file returns empty AST

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I am using Eclipse CDT in a stand-alone Java application as a parser for a C/C++ header file, the idea being to code-generate JNI/JNA bindings from the header.

Downloaded the JAR files (very hard to find, no maven for this library!) and parsed a simple header file which worked just fine.

However when I tried the real header file the results are somewhat random: the AST returned has no children, only some of the pre-processor declarations are present, and most bizarrely only two comments are detected.

Here is the cut-down code:

```
    final FileContent content = FileContent.createForExternalFileLocation("C:/VulkanSDK/1.1.101.0/Include/vulkan/vulkan.h");
    final Map<String, String> definedMacros = new HashMap<>();
    definedMacros.put("__cplusplus", "1");
    final String[] includePaths = new String[0];
    final IScannerInfo info = new ScannerInfo(definedMacros, includePaths);
    final IncludeFileContentProvider emptyIncludes = IncludeFileContentProvider.getEmptyFilesProvider();
    final IIndex index = EmptyCIndex.INSTANCE;
    final int options = 0;
    final IParserLogService log = new DefaultLogService();
    final IASTTranslationUnit unit = GPPLanguage.getDefault().getASTTranslationUnit(content, info, emptyIncludes, index, options, log);
    System.out.println("len="+unit.getChildren().length);
```

The header file I'm trying to parse is for the Vulkan graphics library, it's quite large so here is the [link](https://github.com/ARM-software/vulkan-sdk/blob/master/include/vulkan/vulkan.h) and here is the top few bits of the file:

```
#ifndef VULKAN_H_
#define VULKAN_H_ 1

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

/*
** Copyright (c) 2015-2017 The Khronos Group Inc.
**
** Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
** you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
** You may obtain a copy of the License at
**
**     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
**
** Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
** distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
** WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
** See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
** limitations under the License.
*/

/*
** This header is generated from the Khronos Vulkan XML API Registry.
**
*/


#define VK_VERSION_1_0 1
#include "vk_platform.h"
```

The two comments that are returned by `getComments()` are the first large comment block at the top of the file and oddly enough this:

```
// VULKAN_H_
```

i.e. it appears to have decided that the pre-processor statement is a comment!?

Although the parser accepts a logging callback it doesn't tell me anything and there are no problems reported.  I suspect there is something I'm not understanding about CDT and pre-processor statements but I can't find any similar problems being posted (CDT is a pretty niche tool).

I've fiddled with everything I can think of in the code including the various option parameters but I get the same results every time.  As I said parsing other simpler header files works just fine.

Any ideas? suggestions?

Comment: My recommendation would be: A) figure if the eclipse-cdt people have a forum or mailing list and ask there, SO is only good for niches when the niche people monitor the corresponding tags B) look out for other tooling

Comment: @GhostCat The _Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers_ is downloaded about 1,500 times a day from eclipse.org, not counting the many Eclipse CDT based applications and other distribution channels. I wouldn't call that a niche. What's wrong to use the CDT parser?

Comment: @howlger It was me (the OP) that used the term niche - indeed Eclipse/CDT is definitely NOT niche, but using the underlying C/C++ parser from the CDT tool in a Java application is niche.

Comment: @stridecolossus I'd doubt that too (e. g. see [this GitHub project](https://github.com/ricardojlrufino/eclipse-cdt-standalone-astparser) or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42066626/6505250)). Did you use an AST visitor to find the comments? What's the full AST you get?

Comment: The symptoms sound like perhaps the parser believes that the include guard macro `VULKAN_H_` is already defined, and therefore all the file contents except for the include guard itself are skipped.

Answer (score 0):

So I'm an idiot!

Rather than parsing the actual header file I *thought* I was parsing I'd managed to load the 'super' header file that then #includes the file I actually wanted.  This super-header includes various other headers switching on platform and so on, a standard approach.  The code I posted was not recursing to #included files so the result was correctly empty!  Once I pointed the code at the correct header then the AST was built as expected.

However that doesn't explain the seemingly random comments and the strangely commented out header guard - I've raised a query with the Eclipse CDT developers as (despite my stupidity) the results completely threw me.

For anyone interested code-generating the JNA structures and enumerations from the header worked out nicely (despite CDT not being a 'real' library as such).

Here's an example enumeration class generated from a C `typedef enum`:

```
package org.sarge.jove.platform.vulkan;

/**
 * HEADER COMMENT
 */
public enum VkBorderColor {
    VK_BORDER_COLOR_FLOAT_TRANSPARENT_BLACK(0),     
    VK_BORDER_COLOR_INT_TRANSPARENT_BLACK(1),   
    VK_BORDER_COLOR_FLOAT_OPAQUE_BLACK(2),  
    VK_BORDER_COLOR_INT_OPAQUE_BLACK(3),    
    VK_BORDER_COLOR_FLOAT_OPAQUE_WHITE(4),  
    VK_BORDER_COLOR_INT_OPAQUE_WHITE(5),    
    VK_BORDER_COLOR_BEGIN_RANGE(0),     
    VK_BORDER_COLOR_END_RANGE(5),   
    VK_BORDER_COLOR_RANGE_SIZE(6),  
    VK_BORDER_COLOR_MAX_ENUM(2147483647);   

    private final int value;

    private VkBorderColor(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    /**
     * @return Enum literal
     */
    public int value() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Using an actual C/C++ parser means I could get access to the actual enumerated values, even those that are expressions.

And here is a JNA structure generated from a C `struct`:

```
package org.sarge.jove.platform.vulkan;

import com.sun.jna.Structure;
import com.sun.jna.Structure.FieldOrder;
import com.sun.jna.Pointer;
import org.sarge.jove.platform.vulkan.VkStructureType;

/**
 * HEADER COMMENT
 */
@FieldOrder({
    "sType",
    "pNext",
    "physicalDeviceCount",
    "physicalDevices",
    "subsetAllocation"
})
public class VkPhysicalDeviceGroupProperties extends Structure {
    public static class ByValue extends VkPhysicalDeviceGroupProperties implements Structure.ByValue { }
    public static class ByReference extends VkPhysicalDeviceGroupProperties implements Structure.ByReference { }

    public final int sType = VkStructureType.VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PHYSICAL_DEVICE_GROUP_PROPERTIES.value();
    public Pointer pNext;
    public int physicalDeviceCount;
    public Pointer[] physicalDevices = new Pointer[32];
    public int subsetAllocation;
}
```

Many Vulkan structures have an `sType` field to identify the type of the structure (!) so I could auto-magically initialise the field to the corresponding generated enumeration - sweet.

Again using CDT also meant I could handle the mapping of C array types and initialise array fields (a requirement for JNA memory management).

So in the end CDT worked out well.

Moral of the story: Remember you are an idiot.

Comment: Glad you solved it! The "strangely commented out header guard" looks like the comment that's often written after the `#endif` at the end of the file, to document which `#ifndef` it closes. If you still find the results of parsing your wrapper header unexpected, I would suggest posting its exact contents.